# I am unable to update the value of amount in my cart, I've been trying for hours but with no avail to get it working, I'm using react Hooks

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-hooks

Allright, so I'll try to explain and make sense.

Basically, what I'm done is make a state in React Hooks store with 4 states. One to initially hold the product, one to display the current item which when the users are looking at would give them the ability to add the item to cart, the actual Cart and one for Orders. the state is kept like so:

```
import React, {createContext, useReducer} from "react";
import Reducer from './useStoreReducer'

const initialState = {
    Items: [{
             title : "Shoes", 
             description: "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s",
             price: "99.99",
             imageUrl: "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRVPjDPo_CNSGpoL5NfZL8XzLAzJsrf1-nB_7KP4MI9a55cxZzNsQ&s",
             key: "random",
             id: "random",
             amount: 10,
             totalAmount: 0

         },
         {
             title : "Sweater", 
             description: "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s",
             price: "150",
             imageUrl: "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSntrbto9AejA8UIYyuExTkfIctDY8WEXr-MZxEoUbhypCAjhhN&s",
             key: "shit",
             id: "shit",
             amount: 10,
             totalAmount: 0

         },
         {
             title : "Toy", 
             description: "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s",
             price: "200",
             imageUrl: "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSfZi9v8kkhaKgxJUe02vHi6jeguCm8h6H7Q0zdG6Nogm0deenxUA&s",
             key: "here",
             id: "here",
             amount: 10,
             totalAmount: 0
         },],

    Item: {
        title : "empty", 
        description: "empty",
        price: "empty",
        imageUrl: "empty",
        key: "empty",
        id: "empty",
        amount: 0,
        totalAmount: 0
    },
    Cart: [],
    Orders: [],
    error: null
};

const Store = ({children}) => {
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(Reducer, initialState);
    return (
        <Context.Provider value={[state, dispatch]}>
            {children}
        </Context.Provider>
    )
};

export const Context = createContext(initialState);
export default Store;
```

I also have a page for the reducers like so:

```
const useStoreReducer = (state, action) => {


    switch(action.type) {
        case 'ADD_NEW_ITEM' :
            return {
                ...state,
                Items: [...state.Items, action.payload]
            }
        case 'OPEN_CART' :
            return {
                ...state,
                 Item: action.payload
            }
        case 'ADD_TO_CART' :
            return {
                ...state,
                 Cart: [...state.Cart, action.payload]
            }
        case 'UPDATE_CART_AMOUNT' :
            return {
                ...state,
                Cart: action.payload
                }
        case 'ORDER' :
            return {
                ...state,
                Orders: [...state.Cart, action.payload]
            }
        default: 
            return state
    }
}

export default useStoreReducer;
```

So now, most of the time it works like a charm, when I add new item it goes well, when i open cart (clicking on an item picture opens up a modal which brings up details of an item), and add new item works too. Basically I mapped out a list of elements and when you click on an element, the Item will bring up a modal which I made happen with the function:

```
let [itemModal, toggleItemModal] = useState(false)

 function openItem(id) {
     if (!state.Items.id) {
         dispatch ({
             type: 'OPEN_CART',
             payload: {
                    title : "empty", 
                    description: "empty",
                    price: "empty",
                    imageUrl: "empty",
                    key: "empty",
                    id: null,
                    amount: 0,
                    totalAmount: 0

             }
         })
     }
     toggleItemModal(itemModal = !itemModal);
     const filteredItem = state.Items.filter(item => item.id === id).pop() *//pop because it was returning an array and i needed an object to be displayed in the Item state. Now, I have an individual Item displayed when I click on an item*
     dispatch({
         type: 'OPEN_CART',
         payload: filteredItem
     });
     console.log(state.Item)
 }
```

Now, I want to make sure that when users click on an Item, and add it to cart, if the item exists, update the amount instead of pushing a new item to the cart.

So what I did was, and correct me if I'm wrong, since the state is immutable, i tried to:

```
  let cartCopy = state.Cart; //copy the state first

  function addToCart(itemReference) {  
    const item = itemReference; //pass and as to not mutate the original state, this is the Item state
    item.amount = parseInt(amount); //input handler to get the amount of items entered by the user
    item.totalAmount = (amount*item.price);
    if (state.Cart.some( cartItem => cartItem.id ===  item.id)) { //if item exists in the cart, yields true
      let updatedCart = cartCopy.map( (cartItem) => { // tried to map through each item and if the ID exists, update the amount only
        if (cartItem.id === item.id) {
          cartItem.amount += parseInt(amount)
        }
        return cartItem; 
      }
      )
      console.log(updatedCart) //problem is, it only updates once and then it doesn't run again
    } else {
      alert("added to cart")
    dispatch({
        type: 'ADD_TO_CART',
        payload: item
    });
  }
    updatedAmount(amount = 1)
    props.onHide()
}
```

Can anyone help me see where I went wrong. I am new so it would not surprise me if I did something wrong but I was really careful and read through a lot of documentation, which is why I'm coming here for help

Comment: Instead of pop you can use array.find !

Comment: add a return statement inside the if block if (cartItem.id === item.id) {
          cartItem.amount += parseInt(amount)
 return;
        }

Comment: also why do you need a if block using array.some already in map you are checking for the id ?

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS okay, so the idea of it is,

array.some only returns true if the element exists in the array, so if thats true it wont push a new object into the array.

Array.map finds that element and updates the value, and then replaces the old state with the new updated state, unless im getting something wrong here

but thanks for the array.find tip!!